# How can I receive my NICOP card in USA?

Tags: paperwork, pakistani-citizen, documentation

I applied for renewal of my NICOP card in USA. But the card delivery section in the application remains the same in saying that my card will be delivered in Pakistan, whether I change my permanent address or present address to my USA's one. How can I make it so that my card will be delivered in USA?

Comment: Questions about issued with long-term migration, including ex-pat status etc., belong on [expatriates.se]

Comment: Have you asked this question to NADRA directly? [NADRA's Contacts page](https://www.nadra.gov.pk/contact-us/) lists several methods to do so.